# SQL Server insert new rows ONLY based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I searched in SO but couldn't find anything for my purpose. I need to insert unique rows ONLY from one table into another. I have:

**table1**

```
id  name    bookid bookname start_date   end_date   rel_date   rel_id
1   horror  1221   rockys    04/01/2016  04/30/2016 05/01/2016 4545
2   horror  1331   elm       04/01/2016  04/30/2016 05/01/2016 5656
```

**table2**

```
id  name    bookid bookname start_date   end_date   rel_date   rel_id
1   horror  1221   rockys    04/01/2016  04/30/2016 05/01/2016 4545
2   horror  1441   elm       04/01/2016  04/30/2016 05/01/2016 5656
```

I need to insert into table1 the row with id = 2 in table2 AND also delete the row with id = 2 from table1, because bookid is different even though the rest of the columns match. 
I tried following:

```
insert into table1
select * from table2
where not exists (select * from table2 where table1.id = table2.id
and table1.name = table2.name and table1.bookid = table2.bookid and
table1.bookname = table2.bookname and table1.start_date =  table2.start_date
and table1.end_date = table2.end_date and table1.rel_date =            table2.rel_date
and table1.rel_id = table2.rel_id)
```

Any way I can do all of this in one sql block?

Comment: use joins to delete first and insert next

Comment: on a second thought, if it is the problem with just bookid, why can't write update query with joins?

Comment: You might also look into the `MERGE` command in TSQL.

Comment: @techspider -- In this case it's just bookid, it could be any/all of the remaining columns. I don't have an identify column because this is a sql task inside of a ssis package. 
- Matt

Comment: there is no way you can do this correctly, until you identify an identity column that matches in both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory the following merge statement should achieve what you are looking for.

```
    MERGE table1 [Target]
    USING table2 [Source]
    ON ([Target].[name] = [Source].[name] 
            AND 
        [Target].[bookname] = [Source].[bookname] 
            AND 
        [Target].[start_date] = [Source].[start_date] 
            AND 
        [Target].[end_date] = [Source].[end_date] 
            AND 
        [Target].[rel_date] = [Source].[rel_date] 
            AND 
        [Target].[rel_id] = [Source].[rel_id]  
      )
    WHEN MATCHED AND ([Target].[bookid] <> [Source].[bookid]) THEN
        UPDATE
            SET  [Target].[name]             = [Source].[name]      
                ,[Target].[bookid]           = [Source].[bookid]        
                ,[Target].[bookname]         = [Source].[bookname]  
                ,[Target].[start_date]       = [Source].[start_date]    
                ,[Target].[end_date]         = [Source].[end_date]  
                ,[Target].[rel_date]         = [Source].[rel_date]  
                ,[Target].[rel_id]           = [Source].[rel_id]        
    WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN
    INSERT(         
             [name]         
            ,[bookid]       
            ,[bookname]     
            ,[start_date]   
            ,[end_date]     
            ,[rel_date]     
            ,[rel_id]       
         )
    VALUES
    (       
             [Source].[name]            
            ,[Source].[bookid]      
            ,[Source].[bookname]        
            ,[Source].[start_date]  
            ,[Source].[end_date]        
            ,[Source].[rel_date]        
            ,[Source].[rel_id]  
    );
```

Note that there are some risks and limitations to this approach. If your [id] column has a uniqueness constraint, then it should be set as an identity column otherwise you will run into uniqueness violation errors. Also if [id] column value in table1 is different to [id] column in table2 then merge statement will keep the original [id] value from table1.

Basically this query simply updates your existing record in table1 with the matching record in table2 and insert new records from table2 into table1 if they don’t already exists.

Comment: I don't/can't have any identity columns since this is inside a sql task in ssis package ---> the package won't work if I have an identity column. Essentially what I need is for the update to happen if ANY of the column/s is/are different. The insert should happen only when the start_date is different. So if start_date is the same but any of the columns are different, then it's an update. If start_date is different, then no matter what the rest of the columns have, it's an insert of a new row.
- Matt

Comment: I see, I will need a bit more information though. What column(s) do you want to key on to uniquely identify the records that should be updated? Is it the [id] column or is it a combination of other columns if so which columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just concerned about updating the `bookid` value from `table2`, you can change the value of `bookid` with the below query

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.bookid = t2.bookid
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

If you think your `id` column is not unique in two tables, you might need to consider adding other matching columns in the `JOIN`.

Comment: He did say "the rest of the columns match", so it's possible that his id column isn't unique, so you might need more in your `ON` clause.

Comment: quite unsure what he really wants to do with that example; but anyways, i have added your note; thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to achieve your objective is this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.bookid = T2.bookid
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

However, to answer the question exactly as it was asked:

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND T1.bookid <> T2.bookid

INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT id, name, bookid, bookname, start_date, end_date, rel_date, rel_id
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 T1
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND T1.bookid = T2.bookid
WHERE T1.id IS NULL
```

Note that if your ID fields aren't unique, you'll need to add other conditions to the `ON` clauses.